# JQuery Mobile Can't make back button go away

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, back-button

I have a header in jquery mobile. The header contains a select box, and whenever I put that in I can't seem to make the back button go away. Viz:

```
<div data-backbtn="false" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <div>
    <h1>Test Project</h1>
    <span>Title</span>
    <span style="float:right">
        <select>
            <option selected="selected">Rachel Green</option>
            <option>Chandler Bing</option>
            <option>Monica Gellar</option>
            <option>Ross Gellar</option>
            <option>Joey Tribiani</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    </div>
</div><!-- /header -->
```

If I take out the select the back button goes away. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm works fine for me.

Live Link: http://jsfiddle.net/vrx7X/3/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="home"> 
    <div data-backbtn="false" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <div>
        <h1>Test Project</h1>
        <span>Title</span>
        <span style="float:right">
            <select>
                <option selected="selected">Rachel Green</option>
                <option>Chandler Bing</option>
                <option>Monica Gellar</option>
                <option>Ross Gellar</option>
                <option>Joey Tribiani</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Home Page</li> 
            <li><a href="#next">Next Page</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="next"> 
    <div data-backbtn="false" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <div>
        <h1>Test Project</h1>
        <span>Title</span>
        <span style="float:right">
            <select>
                <option selected="selected">Rachel Green</option>
                <option>Chandler Bing</option>
                <option>Monica Gellar</option>
                <option>Ross Gellar</option>
                <option>Joey Tribiani</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Next Page</li> 
            <li><a href="#home">Home Page</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had an older version of jquery mobile, I guess this is a bug fix that was introduced. I appreciate your help.